# Command a java class with PHP with a raspberry

Tags: php, linux

I'm a new user of this forum and after many hours to search everywhere on the web, I've never found a good explanation about my issue.
I begin to program with a raspberry and i can lauch this line with an ssh console without problem (`sudo java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ControlGpioExample`) but when I put it in an PHP exec command nothing happen. here is my command :

```
$output = shell_exec("java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ControlGpioExample", $output); 

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

My apache server run correctly (It's work)
My PHP script is in `var/www` directory.
I'm a beginner with linux and I think that my problem comes from access right.
Thank you for your Help

Comment: instead of . and classes, try to put in the absolute path.

Comment: What does your http servers error log file say? It should tell you what the issue is.

Comment: Here is a solution even though it is for Python, http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7365/php-to-execute-python-scripts-for-gpio

Comment: Try it with `$output = shell_exec("java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ControlGpioExample 2>&1"); ` to redirect stderr to stdout. shell_exec only returns the output to stdout; so by default you will probably miss error messages (like e.g. java not being in the PATH of the process running php).